# how to reduce duplicated code of same exception catching operation used in multiple places?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

To work with multiple methods i have to use the same checked exception `catch` many times (see [Java: checked vs unchecked exception explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115896/java-checked-vs-unchecked-exception-explanation)). The result is duplicated lines of code. I would like some way of reducing the duplicated exception `catch` to reduce the number of lines of code.

What is a good way to reduce the number of duplicated `catch` sections and decrease the lines of code? Is there any way that I can write that `catch` operation in one another file and use that explicitly?

Basically i want to reduce line count and make the code more concise and easier to read.

Here is an example of my code:

```
@RequestMapping(value="")
public @ResponseBody Response addMultiple(){
if() {
    try {
        data = new weight();

    } 
    catch( AmazonServiceException se ){
        response = x;
    }
    catch (AmazonClientException ce) {
        response = y;
    }
    catch(JsonProcessingException je) {
        response = z;
    }
}


@RequestMapping(value="")
public @ResponseBody Response addMultiple2(){
if() {
    try {
        data = new height();

    } 
    catch( AmazonServiceException se ){
        response = x;
    }
    catch (AmazonClientException ce) {
        response = y;
    }
    catch(JsonProcessingException je) {
        response = z;
    }
}

@RequestMapping(value="")
public @ResponseBody Response addMultiple3(){
if() {
    try {
        data = new age();

    } 
    catch( AmazonServiceException se ){
        response = x;
    }
    catch (AmazonClientException ce) {
        response = y;
    }
    catch(JsonProcessingException je) {
        response = z;
    }
}
```

I want declare that exception catching operation once, and want to call it multiple time.

I am using Spring framework.

Comment: are these exceptions checked or unchecked ?

Comment: exceptions are checked..

Comment: @RomanC I don't see how this question is a duplicate of the marked one.

Comment: The question leaves a lot to interpretation: what are `x`, `y` and `z`? Are the always the same? What really changes between `addMultiple` and `addMultiple2`? It would really help if you didn't post stub code but a real (simple) implementation.

Comment: @RomanC Totally agree with Michael Markidis: I don't see how this question is a duplicate of the marked one. It isn't, really.

Answer (score 3):

A general way to handle it could be to create a method that can handle all your exception types and return a `Response` object based on the passed in `Exception`.

**The `handleException` method**:

```
public static Response handleException (Exception e)
{
    Response res = null;

    if (e instanceof AmazonServiceException)
    {
        res = x;
    }
    else if (e instanceof AmazonClientException)
    {
        res = y;
    }
    else if (e instanceof JsonProcessingException)
    {
        res = z;
    }
    else // if we get any other exception
    {
        res = xyz;
        // OR you can throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    return res;
}
```

Now, all the calling code where you don't want to repeat all the exception handling would use it like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="")
public @ResponseBody Response addMultiple(){
    if() {
        try {
            data = new weight();
        } 
    // Use this same catch block in the other addMultiple() methods
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        response = handleException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Michael, I am curious to know if at this year (2019) and with all the changes to the language, do you still think this is the best solution or do you think that we could use something different now? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You'd write a custom exception handler in Spring if you want to handle these exception and take some action, the handler will take if there any exception occurs, also you can omit the `try-catch` blocks.

```
@ExceptionHandler({ Exception.class }) //narrow it to the exception you need
    public ModelAndView globalExceptionHandler(Exception e) {
        return new ModelAndView("error");
    }
```

Otherwise catch `Exception` in your methods and write a handler method to handle it in catch block.

change catch block with

```
catch( Exception e ){
    handleException(e);
}
```

and handler below

```
private Response handleException(Exception e){
    if(e instanceof E1){

    }else if(e instanceof E2){

    }
    .
    .
    .
    return response;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer of @UUID will allow you to handle exceptions outside the context of the function. If you want to handle them inside the function, you can write a `handleException` method, that will allow you return values and have parameters:

```
public class ExceptionHandler {

    public static Response handleWebException(Object ... parameters) {
        return ... some result ...;

    }
}
```

In your method you call

```
public @ResponseBody Response addMultiple2(){
    if() {
        try {
            data = new height();

        } 
        catch( Exception ex ){
            return ExceptionHandler.handleWebException(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a custom exception handler class, where you can pass the exception and use it across all the classes

Basically something like this that would handle any exception and can be used across all classes.

```
  @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
  public ModelAndView handleError(HttpServletRequest req, Exception exception) {
    logger.error("Request: " + req.getRequestURL() + " raised " + exception);

    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    mav.addObject("exception", exception);
    mav.addObject("url", req.getRequestURL());
    mav.setViewName("error");
    return mav;
  }
```